# Sammy mustache - not working (variables in double braces not replaced with values)

Tags: jquery, mustache, couchapp, sammy.js

I'm trying to write my first webapp using sammy and mustache templating. The template doesn't seem to render correctly (variables in double braces are not replaced with values). Here's the relevent part of index.html --

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sammy/sammy.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="site.js"></script>

  <a href="#/hello">Hello</a>

  <div id="container">
  </div>
```

And the relevent part of site.js--

```
$(function () { 
  app.s = $.sammy("#container", function () {
    this.use('Mustache', 'ms');
    // Index of all databases
    this.get('', app.index);
    this.get("#/", app.index);
    this.get("#/hello", function(context) {
        context.name = "Ram";
        context.partial('hello.ms', {name:"Ram"});
    });
  })
  app.s.run();
});
```

And this is my simple template (hello.ms)--

```
Hello {{name}}.
```

When I click on the Hello link, it is rendered as

> Hello {{name}}.

what I expect is:

> Hello Ram.

Any hints what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks.

PS. The basic structure is generated using "couchapp boiler myapp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, I'd forgotten to include "sammy.mustache.js". I thought doing a this.use('Mustache') would automatically load it!